# Making a security definition request to FIX adapter

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am trying to make a request (Security Definition Request) to FIX Adapter using the following method. This is an application level call and I manually invoke this method whenever there is a successful connection to FIX Adapter.

WHen i run this method i get a "Field not found for tag:49" exception message. However SecurityDefinitionRequest class doesnt allow me to set Tag 49 (SenderCompId) to it.

First of all is this the right way to make a SecurityDefinitionRequest? I tried looking at QuickFix/N docs but they dont explain how to make such request.

http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/sending-messages.html

Infact i havent seen any articles so far in the internet. Any suggestions?

```
public void ToApp(Message message, SessionID sessionId)
{        
    var request =
        new SecurityDefinitionRequest()
        {
            SecurityReqID = new SecurityReqID("1"),
            SecurityID = new SecurityID("5"),
            SecurityRequestType = new SecurityRequestType(3),
            SecurityType = new SecurityType("FUT")
        };

    request.SetField(new SenderCompID("217"));
    Session.SendToTarget(request);  
 }
```

The constructed message looks like this

```
    8=FIX.4.29=3735=c48=549=217167=FUT320=1321=310=003
```

Comment: SenderCompId is part of the standard FIX spec. There shouldn't be a reason you can't add it in SecurityDefinitionRequest. Maybe you have to cast to a base class?

Comment: Even if i do something like request.SetField(new SenderCompID("217")); which is Tag 49. QuickFix still cannot find Tag 49.

Comment: What FIX version are you using?

Comment: 4.2 I have included the constructed message

Comment: Just tried on linqpad. `Console.WriteLine(sec);`  Works for me..

Comment: Sorry didnt get what you meant by this Console.WriteLine(sec);

Comment: Do a dump of the object, as in print the contents of `.ToString()`

Comment: Actually it's your  constructed message...

Comment: Yes the message is fine but the moment the application hits this line Session.SendToTarget(request); it blows up saying the Tag 49 is missing. However it is clearly specified in the message 49=217

Comment: Mmn.. then dunno. Did you try configuring it as in http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/sending-messages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest:

```
SessionId currentSessionId = new QuickFix.SessionID("FIX4.2", "217","CBOE");
securityDefinitionRequest.SetSessionID(currentSessionId );
```

Comment: Hi Lewis. Please update your answer to this securityDefinitionRequest.SetSessionId(sessionId). The sessionId will be the current session's sessionId. This worked for me. So once updated i'll accept your answer